# How can I change the visibility of another object in the same ListBox in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone

An excerpt from my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
                <Image Name="like" Source="/Images/Like1.png"  Tap="like_Tap"/>
                <Image Name="unlike" Visibility="Collapsed"  Source="/Images/UNLike1.png" Tap="unlike_Tap"/>
                <Image Name="comment" Source="/Images/Comment1.png" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now here is my problem

In my C# code:

```
private void like_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{     
  // Here I'm unable to change the visibility of either image. How do I do this?
}
```

I would like this behaviour to spread to the unlike button too.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the image in code I would recommend use `binding` to achieve this.

Create property of bool type in your `Item` class and bind that property with `Visibility` property of image. You need [Visibility To Boolean Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

```
 <Image Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowLikeImage Converter={Static Resource VisibilityToBooleanConverter}}"  Source="/Images/UNLike1.png" Tap="unlike_Tap"/>
```

On the tap event you will just have to change the `ShowLikeImage` property and UI will automatically update itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to do it in a different way, using it as a multipurpose button.

Your XAML would be like this:

```
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
            <Image Name="Likebtn" Source="/Images/Like1.png"  Tap="Likebtn_Tap"/>
            <Image Name="commentbtn" Source="/Images/Comment1.png" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>
```

Your method would then be like this:

```
private void Likebtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    if (img == null) return;
    switch (img.Source.ToString())
    {
       case "The like button's location":
           //change do your like logic, and then change it to an unlike button
           break;
       //the opposite for the unlike button's location
    }
}
```